# PostgreSql Select Query maniuplation

Tags: postgresql, select

I work with PostgreSQL 9.2 and I want to make select

```
  psql -h localhost -U user -c "select var_val from public.config where var_name='test_key'"
```

result is

```
var_val 
---------
 90
(1 row)
```

but i want only `90`

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you just expecting the value 90 to be outputted without the other formatting and the result count? Maybe start with this information: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html

Comment: +1 because you mentioned your version, though this is a bit of a read-the-manual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [user manual for `psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) would be a good starting point.

Try `psql -t -A`.